# Retain intersecting objects in two arrays of objects by comparing the values of a particular shared property/column

Tags: php, arrays, object, array-intersect

I'm looking for a succinct way of comparing arrays of objects in PHP. I know I could just check for equal sized arrays and then loop through one array looking for each object in the second array, but I thought it would be nicer to use one or more of the array comparison functions.

I've tested a couple arrays of objects and the main problem I'm coming up against is that the array comparison functions insist on comparing elements as `strings`, like this:

```
class Foo{
    public $pk=NULL;
    function __construct($pk){
        $this->pk=$pk;
    }

    function __toString(){
        return (string)$this->pk;//even an integer must be cast or array_intersect fails
    }
}

for($i=1;$i<7;$i++){
    $arr1[]=new Foo($i);
}
for($i=2;$i<5;$i++){
    $arr2[]=new Foo($i);
}

$int=array_intersect($arr1,$arr2);
print_r($int);
```

outputs

```
Array
(
[1] => Foo Object
    (
        [pk] => 2
    )

[2] => Foo Object
    (
        [pk] => 3
    )

[3] => Foo Object
    (
        [pk] => 4
    )
```

)

That's fine if the objects have `__toString()` methods and if those `__toString()` methods return a unique identifier and never `''`.

But what happens if that's not the case, say for an object like this:

```
class Bar{
    public $pk=NULL;
    function __construct($pk){
        $this->pk=$pk;
    }

    function __toString(){
        return 'I like candy.';//same for all instances
    }

    function Equals(self $other){
        return ($this->pk==$other->pk);
    }

}
```

Is it possible to do `array_uintersect($arr1,$arr2,$somecallback)` that forces the use of `Foo::Equals()`? From what I can see the conversion to `string` happens before the callback is called.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `array_uintersect` for this.

Some example code:

```
class Fos {
    public $a = 0;
    function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
    static function compare($a, $b) {
        if ($a->a == $b->a) return 0;
        if ($a->a > $b->a) return 1;
        if ($a->a < $b->a) return -1;
    }
}

$fos1 = array();
$fos2 = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $fos1[] = new Fos($i);
}

for ($i = 8; $i < 18; $i++) {
    $fos2[] = new Fos($i);
}

$fosi = array_uintersect($fos1, $fos2, array('Fos','compare'));
```

Comment: Nice! I always forget about the `array('Fos','compare')` notation for indicating the callback function belongs to a class.  Any idea where that notation is documented? I only ever trip over it in the occasional example.

Comment: @dnagirl: See PHP manual here: http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig: many thanks! Sometimes it's really hard to find things when you don't know what they're called.

Answer (score 0):

The more modern equivalent of @kapa's answer can use an anonymous callback function with arrow function syntax and the spaceship operator for returning the 3-way comparison integer. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9MZue))

```
class Foo {
    public $pk;
    function __construct($v) {
        $this->pk = $v;
    }
}

$foo1 = [];
$foo2 = [];

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $foo1[] = new Foo($i);
}

for ($i = 8; $i < 18; ++$i) {
    $foo2[] = new Foo($i);
}

var_export(
    array_uintersect($foo1, $foo2, fn($a, $b) => $a->pk <=> $b->pk)
);
```