# PHP array_diff with instances or custom callback function?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have many arrays, each holding instances of `Product`. Need to get unique products only. From PHP documentation of [`array_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
array array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
```

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 ===
>   (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

Does this mean I'm forced to implement `toString()` in my instances? Is there any function to compute the difference providing a custom callback?

I didn't tested this code, but I guess it will not work because there is no `toString()` function in `Product`:

```php
$categories = array();
// ...

// Unique products from all categories, compared against ===
$uniqueProducts = array();

// Compute unique products
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $uniqueProducts += array_diff($category->getProducts(), $uniqueProducts)
}

return $uniqueProducts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean I'm forced to implement toString() in my instances?

According to the [typecast section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) in the PHP docs manual - you do not need a `toString()` function. Basically typecasting (string) is the same as if you simply did `var_dump($uniqueProducts)`

All that the array_diff is doing is typecasting your array.

One option is to make your own "array_diff" function

```
function my_array_diff($arraya, $arrayb)
{
    foreach ($arraya as $keya => $valuea)
    {
        // Put your own 'test' here - but for example this uses in_array()
        if (in_array($valuea, $arrayb))
        {
            unset($arraya[$keya]);
        }
    }
    return $arraya;
}
```

Comment: Is typecasting safe for objects? That is, two identical instances will give the same string representation?

Comment: tbh - I'm not sure - hence why I included your very own "my_array_diff()" that you can customise how you want to check your objects to look for specific differences/similarities without a typecast

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I was looking for a one-line (elegant) way of doing this check.

Comment: Well - it is a "one-line" code in your main section - then put "my_array_diff()" somewhere else (maybe in an include file or something)

Comment: Your only other option is to try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347293/comparing-arrays-of-objects - but that also uses custom code

Answer (score 0):

If the product lists are short you could implement your own checking, based on values of your choice?

```
$uniqueProducts = array();
foreach($productsOne as $productOne) {
  foreach($uniqueProducts as $alreadyListed) {
    if($productOne->getName() != $alreadyListes->getName()) { // You can customise this line to make more specific
      break;
    }
    $uniqueProducts = $productOne; // If product hasn't already been added to the array then it's unique.
  }
}
// Repeat foreaches for second product array, or combine them before teh foreach using $productOne = $productOne+$productTwo.
```

Comment: Of course I could but I was looking for an elegant solution. Thanks anyways.